# How to download Signed Document from an Envelope?

Tags: docusignapi

Once a user signs a document attached to an envelope, is there anyway that developer can download that document using Rest API end-point? And before downloading it, is there any way to tell whether the document is signed or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Part I: Determine whether a particular signer OR whether all recipients have completed/submitted an Envelope**

To check whether a particular Signer (recipient) has completed signing an Envelope, you can use the [List Envelope Recipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list) request:

`GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients`

As shown [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list/#examples), the `signers` property within the JSON response is the array of signers for the Envelope, and the `status` property within each **signer** object indicates that particular recipient's status.  A status of **completed** for a **signer** indicates that the recipient has signed/completed/submitted the Envelope.

```
{
    ...
    "signers": [
        {
            "deliveredDateTime": "2016-10-05T21:18:12.3330000Z",
            "email": "jallard@example.com",
            "isBulkRecipient": "false",
            "name": "Jennie Allard",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "recipientIdGuid": "4575d5e9-7654-467b-b2f5-6c59ca7c43f8",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "signedDateTime": "2016-10-05T21:18:41.6930000Z",
            "status": "completed",
            "userId": "ca45284a-a94e-4ee2-90af-76035bd795b2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Alternatively, to check whether ***ALL*** recipients of an Envelope have completed/submitted the Envelope, you can use the [Get Envelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/get/) request:

`GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}`

As shown [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/get/#examples), the response will be an **Envelope** object and the `status` property within that object indicates the overall status of the Envelope. A `status` of **completed** indicates that all recipients have completed/submitted the Envelope.

**Part II: Download completed document(s)**

For endpoints related to retrieving document(s) for an Envelope, see this page: https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/. You'll likely use the [List Envelope Documents](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/list) request to get the list of documents in the Envelope, and then subsequently issue a [Get Envelope Document](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get) request for each document that you want to retrieve.

**Additional comments**

While you certainly can use REST API requests as I've described above to periodically poll for Envelope (or Recipient) status, and then request document(s) when envelope (and/or recipient) status is completed -- a more efficient alternative would be to use [DocuSign Connect](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/connect-guide.pdf), which you could configure to automatically push Envelope status and documents to an endpoint you specify when an Envelope reaches **status = completed**.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed response. I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, happy I could help.

Comment: Yeah Kim! Thank you for your time and answers!!